# Core Games Scripting : Line of sight

Tags: lua, game-engine, coregames

so I'm working with a gaming engine called [**Core**](https://www.coregames.com/?gclid=Cj0KCQjw4f35BRDBARIsAPePBHwWVA0nIwCEtFVzGi0QvFDtmBfvuNASH1QZcZvyRiC1OUvRrSm_9ngaAutBEALw_wcB) whos scripts are written in Lua. And I'm having trouble writing a script to detect line of sight, I cant seem to find any other help scripting this in Cores function document and as it is a relatively new engine I also can't find any others with this issue.

If anyone knows how to detect line of sight in a Core script I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

What I think you need is World.Raycast(), which takes a Vector3 for the start and end point. There is an example here: https://docs.coregames.com/api/hitresult/#examples that gets a HitResult based on a starting position Vector3 and a camera direction:

```lua
local rayStart = player:GetViewWorldPosition()
local cameraForward = player:GetViewWorldRotation() * Vector3.FORWARD
local rayEnd = rayStart + cameraForward * 10000

local hitResult = World.Raycast(rayStart, rayEnd)
```